# How do I get this pig latin code to function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This pig latin code I made seems to be fine, but it asks for input and then outputs the input itself. What's wrong here?

```
def pig_latin(string_x):
    word_list=string_x.split()
    for item in word_list:
        if (item[:1]).lower() in ["a",'e','i','o','u']:
            item+='ay'
        else:
            item=item[1:]+item[:1]+'ay'
    print(" ".join(word_list))

x=input()
pig_latin(x)
```

Comment: You have to use `x=input("Input something : ")`

Comment: Otherwise your code will do this: `pig_latin("Input something : ")`.

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry, but that's a typo on my part. I've used x=input() and it still doesn't function

Comment: @T.Feix while you are right about that, there are bigger problems. I believe the `str(...)` bit was added after the fact

Comment: @user9605362 btw- you'll need to tag a person when they comment otherwise they won't get notified

Comment: @DillonDavis well thanks for that info. I'm kinda new to the site.

Comment: Also @user9605362, your problem is that `item = ...` assigns to the variable `item`, not to the element of the list. You'll need to create a new list and `.append()` to it your `item`s.

Comment: I really think you've made a mistake in your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign to `item`, you are changing the variable `item`, but not the value of that element in the list. You want something like:

```
def pig_latin(string_x):
    word_list=string_x.split()
    new_word_list = []
    for item in word_list:
        if (item[:1]).lower() in ["a",'e','i','o','u']:
            new_word_list.append(item+'ay')
        else:
            new_word_list.append(item[1:]+item[:1]+'ay')
    print(" ".join(new_word_list))

x=input()
pig_latin(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def pig_latin(string_x):
    word_list = string_x.split()
    translated = []
    for item in word_list:
        if (item[:1]).lower() in ["a", 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']:
            item += 'ay'
        else:
            item = item[1:] + item[:1] + 'ay'
        translated.append(item)
    print(" ".join(translated))

x = input("Input something : ")
pig_latin(x)
```

There were a few problems:

- If you want to accept user input you need to use `input` instead of `str`
- You need to be able to store the items you've created in case the user inputs multiple words, so I created the `translated` list.
- You were printing the word list in your output which was just a split version of the input.